# Asynchronous function vs child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know what is the difference between using an asynchronous function (**setInterval**) in the main process or run it in a child one.

The main process englobes serving https request using the express framework, would it be a possibility where both async process (**incoming http** and **setInterval** step) crash?

Both process have to be reliable and run in relative parallel way.

Comment: Hi victor, welcome to the community. `child_process` creates another process, while an `async function` is run in the same process.

Comment: could the `async functions` crash if both are fired?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: I mean that they don't run

Comment: Did you mean Clash??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference is `setInterval` sets a timer to run in the same process. While `child_process` spins up a new process.

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Also, child processes do not have to be asynchronous.

Comment: I mean if 2 async funcitions run in the same process what at the same time what happens

Comment: @victor that's what Node.js is all about, so what happens is that that will work just fine.